# Pre-loading the context before it's being used

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

This is hard to explain so bear with me.

I have an Entity Framework Context being used by a View Model. Essentially, it is a search box which has a service which uses the context to run queries based on the search criteria.

The problem is, when the **first search** is performed, the `DbContext` then kicks into action and looks at the database to generate the entities and relationships. (At least this is what I think is happening)

This is demonstrated below:

[image: Initial search]

The first search takes a few seconds, as Entity Framework is doing it's thing. After the first search is performed, **all other searches** that are performed happen pretty much instantaneously. It's just the **first search** which takes a long time.

[image: Search results]

Now, onto my question.

Is it possible to force the `DbContext` to load the relationships and generally do it's thing (asynchronously) before any action is performed on the context? i.e a query.

Ideally, the first search should be as quick as the other searches.

Comment: I think it cache, it's not because of generating dbcontext relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply query the entities, but do nothing with them. The `dbContext` then caches the results.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but I was looking for a more... *elegant* solution. Perhaps a property I can reference when instantiating the DbContext for example. If not, then I'm happy to mark this as the answer :-)

Comment: well, if the DbContext would pre-load all rows of the database, this could become a huge performance issue. Most databases store many gigabytes of data which will have to be pre-loaded (if you have enough RAM to store it). But even with small amounts of data (e.g. 50 MB) it will take relatively long to load all rows.

Comment: An elegant solution would be to create an extension method that iterates through all tables and loads their content, but there is no such option in the DbContext class.

Comment: As far as I am aware, Entity Framework does not *store* anything (actual records). You only execute queries where data is only loaded when the query is executed. I'm fairly certain I get get away with just doing a `FirstOrDefault` on any `DbSet` in the Context, and that should take care of everything, without loading tonnes of data.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you mean. If the context does not store/cache the records and would have to reload all entities for each query. I'm assuming that loading the data is the expensive operation of course.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain if **all** records are cached, but I would certainly doubt that is the case. Queries are *select statements* up until the point of which they are assigned to a variable, at this point, the query is then executed and the data from said query is cached. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/hh949853.aspx#2) seems to explain the process. That said however, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

What is taking a lot of time on first use is dependant on the size of your db schema (building EF's virtual tables) and done once at runtime on first instantiation.

Just initialise a context on another thread at startup and do any query on it and it will take that performance hit asynchronously.

Don't try to keep a reference to that context either, creating contexts is cheap and they are meant to be short lived, what is expensive is only the first time you create one in your process.

If the slowdown is an issue even asynchronously you can have EF do this work at compile time but it is somewhat involved